# TypeError: dataModel is undefined when loading animation in browser

Tags: javascript, html, json, adobe-edge

I'm having issues getting an animated infographic to load in a webpage and was hoping for some help.

The animation was created in Adobe Edge and embedded in an iFrame in the webpage. It pulls data from a json file which is located in the same directory as the webpage.

**Issue**
In all browsers I'm getting the error `TypeError: dataModel is undefined` in the console window, however in Chrome and IE I also have the error `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)` in relation to the json file. The json file isn't being recognised in Chrome or IE. I've validated it and included the script `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>` in the `<head>` tags for the page.

Locally the webpage loads the animation correctly in Firefox and Safari but once on the server it breaks.

Here's a link to the webpage in question: http://westernstations.net/courses/crossrail/C110.html

**JS Code**

```
var dataModel;

$.getJSON( "stations.json", function( json ){
    dataModel = json;
});

var index = -1;

function handleClickEvent( id ){

    // Handle timeline trigger clicks
    showDetail(id);
}
// Expose to globally accessible scope
sym.setVariable("handleClickEvent", handleClickEvent);


/*****************************************************
 * Controller for data and view state
 */
var timeoutDelay = 500;

function setState( id, state ){

    var symbol = sym.getSymbol(id);
    if( symbol ){
        symbol.setVariable("selected", state); 
        symbol.play(state ? "rollover" : "rollout");
    }
}

function showDetail( id ){

    // Reset last timeline selection
    setState("Trigger"+index, false);

    // Save new selection
    index = id;

    // Select next timeline trigger
    setState("Trigger"+index, true);

    // Show details
    var data = dataModel[index];
    var anim = sym.getSymbol("DetailPanelAnimation");
    var details = anim.getSymbol("DetailPanel");
    if( details )
    {
         // Transition out
         if( anim.getPosition() > 0 ){
            anim.play("hide");
         }

    // Transition in with new data...
    setTimeout(function()
    {
        details.$("Caption").html(data.title);
        details.$("Details").html(data.text);
        anim.play("show");
    }, 
    timeoutDelay);
    }
}
```

As a rookie when it comes to js, any help would be much appreciated.